# External Stage - Blob vs Gen2

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Any inputs on which storage to be used when integrating Azure and Snowflake? Do we lose any functionality if switching between storages?

Comment: Hi - please can you clarify what you mean by "integrating Azure and Snowflake"? Given that the type of storage doesn't affect Snowflake, I assume that this is really about Azure - so what is your question about Azure storage?

Comment: Type of storage does affect the ability for Snowflake to load/unload data via a stage, however.  Blob is currently the only GA method on Azure, but Gen2 is Preview availability.  As far as I know, there is no functionality differences between the two, however.